# CiviRules - where is the data stored in the database? - backdating

Tags: civirules

I've got a CiviRule that triggers when a membership is added and is delayed by 3 months, but i want to back date it for existing memberships, ie any membership less than 90 days old (if it was 88 days old, my rule would act in 2 days time)

Assuming there's not a clever way of doing this up front, i'm happy to manipulate things directly in the database, but haven't found anything but the civirule_rule_log which actually changes on triggered conditions - where is the part that acts?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be really careful of what you are doing. But the delayed actions are stored in the `civicrm_queue_item` database table.

The column `release_time` indicates the date from which the action is going to be executed. The data for the action is stored as a serialized data blob in the column `data`.

Comment: Aha, great - thanks! and yes, i'll be testing a lot before deciding whether or not to make any changes to the live site!